# How data gets loaded into snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

1)How does data gets loaded into snow flake, if it is from external source,
2)i am confused and in snow flake where does the data gets stored
3) if it is AWS where does s3 buckets come into picture

Answer (score 0):

When data is loaded into Snowflake, Snowflake reorganizes that data into its internal optimized, compressed, columnar format. Snowflake stores this optimized data in cloud storage.

Snowflake manages all aspects of how this data is stored — the organization, file size, structure, compression, metadata, statistics, and other aspects of data storage are handled by Snowflake. The data objects stored by Snowflake are not directly visible nor accessible by customers; they are only accessible through SQL query operations run using Snowflake.

[Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html#database-storage)

Comment: how does data load from external source to s3 buckets